# Inputting Grades with Looping C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

We're only interested in the #'s in the range [0,100]. There may be number outside the range [0, 100], but they aren't part of our calculation (i.e numbers below 0 and above 100 can be inputted but will be ignored in the calculations and counters).
Assume we assign ABCDF as
    [85,100]:   A
    [75,85):    B
    [65,75):    C
    [55,65):    D
    [0,55): F
For each of the five letter grades, output the number of scores with that grade, and also, if the number of scores wasn't 0, output the average score with that grade. Also, if the number of valid scores (in [0, 100]) wasn't 0, output the average of all the scores

I am having trouble with this looping question. When I input multiple scores, it loops them incorrectly and outputs two sets of grades for each input rather than the example answer shown above. Also I am not sure if my break is placed correctly to exit the program when a word is inputted. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        double scores;
        unsigned countA = 0;
        unsigned countB = 0;
        unsigned countC = 0;
        unsigned countD = 0;
        unsigned countF = 0;
        char grade;
        double sumA = 0, sumB = 0, sumC = 0, sumD = 0, sumF = 0;
        cout << "Enter scores: ";
        for (scores; cin >> scores;){
            if (scores > 85 && scores <= 100){
                grade = 'A';
                countA++;
                sumA += scores;
            }
            else if (scores > 75){
                grade = 'B';
                countB++;
                sumB += scores;
            }
            else if (scores > 65){
                grade = 'C';
                countC++;
                sumC += scores;
            }
            else if (scores > 55){
                grade = 'D';
                countD++;
                sumD += scores;
            }
            else{
                grade = 'F';
                countF++;
                sumF += scores;
            }
            if (!cin){
                break;
            }
        if (countA == 0){
            cout << "# A's: 0 " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "# A's: " << countA << " Average = " <<  sumA/countA << endl;
        } if (countB == 0){
            cout << "# B's : 0 " << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "# B's: " << countB << " Average = " << sumB /countB << endl;
        } if (countC == 0){
    cout << "# C's: 0 " << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "# C's: " << countC << " Average = " << sumC /countC << endl;
        } if (countD == 0){
            cout << "# D's: 0 " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "# D's: " << countD << " Average = " << sumD /countD << endl;
        } if (countF == 0){
            cout << "# F's: 0 " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "# F's: " << countF << " Average = " << sumF /countF << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I altered my code deleting the bunch of if and else statements at the end to this:   
 cout << "# A's : " << countA << " Average = " << sumA / sumA << endl; for each grade but it did not make a difference

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying the problem is, try to be a bit clearer. But I can see `for (scores; cin >> scores;){` should be `while (cin >> scores){` and `if (!cin){ break; }` is unnecessary (the if can never be true) and should be deleted.

Comment: Swap `for (scores; cin >> scores;)` for `while (cin >> scores)` does the same thing (loop until something other than a double is input), but cleaner. `if (!cin)` is not needed. And the loop is missing the terminating brace, making the remainder of the code part of the loop. And not compile, but you can't always win.

Comment: @user4581301, you should make that an answer, you are clearly right.

Comment: what i Mean is lets say i In put 3 scores into my program. 96 98 99. My program should output "#As: 3 Average = 97.6667" but instead it outputs each number one at a time where #As will always be 1 and the average will always be the number inputted. Also I made those changes but it still displays the same format. I'm thinking it may be a brace issue but not entirely sure @user4581301

Comment: @john Yeah. Looks like I'll have to answer this in full form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR version: Closing brace on the for loop was missing. Loop never ended and caused OP's output code to also loop.

Long version:

Here is working code. The stuff I changed is marked with comments.

```
#include <iostream> //removed a bunch of unused includes.
using std::cin;    // including all of namespace::std is overkill and often
using std::cout;   // leads to hard-to-solve bugs. Only use what you need
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    double scores;
    unsigned countA = 0;
    unsigned countB = 0;
    unsigned countC = 0;
    unsigned countD = 0;
    unsigned countF = 0;
    char grade;
    double sumA = 0, sumB = 0, sumC = 0, sumD = 0, sumF = 0;
    cout << "Enter scores: ";
//    for (scores; cin >> scores;){
    while (cin >> scores) // cleaner
    {
        if (scores > 85 && scores <= 100)
        {
            grade = 'A';
            countA++;
            sumA += scores;
        }
        else if (scores > 75)
        {
            grade = 'B';
            countB++;
            sumB += scores;
        }
        else if (scores > 65)
        {
            grade = 'C';
            countC++;
            sumC += scores;
        }
        else if (scores > 55)
        {
            grade = 'D';
            countD++;
            sumD += scores;
        }
        else
        {
            grade = 'F';
            countF++;
            sumF += scores;
        }
// this test is made redundant by the loop condition
//        if (!cin)
//        {
//            break;
//        }
    } // this was missing. The loop kept going and included all of
      // the following code in the loop.
    if (countA == 0)
    {
        cout << "# A's: 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "# A's: " << countA << " Average = " << sumA / countA << endl;
    }
    if (countB == 0)
    {
        cout << "# B's : 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "# B's: " << countB << " Average = " << sumB / countB << endl;
    }
    if (countC == 0)
    {
        cout << "# C's: 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "# C's: " << countC << " Average = " << sumC / countC << endl;
    }
    if (countD == 0)
    {
        cout << "# D's: 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "# D's: " << countD << " Average = " << sumD / countD << endl;
    }
    if (countF == 0)
    {
        cout << "# F's: 0 " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "# F's: " << countF << " Average = " << sumF / countF << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!! I was stuck on this for a while, I truly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, I assume your main issue is the output part. Currently your code produces [this.](http://ideone.com/7GILhF)

As you see we get intermediate output, after every score entered. To change that the loop needs to be split into two loops: One for input, and one for output that runs after the first:

```
while (/* we get scores */) {
 // update the counters and sums
}
for (/* every score */) {
 // print count and average
}
```

To generate the output in a loop you need to store your data in some "loopable" way. Currently you have multiple local variables. Changing that to an array (indexed by the respective grade) allows us to loop over the data:

```
unsigned counter[5];
double sum [5];
// A -> 0, B -> 1, ..., F -> 4
for (std::size_t it = 0; it < 5; ++it) {
 // use sum[it] and counter[it]
}
```

But raw arrays (as raw pointers) are evil - only use them when absolutely necessary - we use `std::array` from the standard library. And to ease iteration and improve logical encapsulation it's good to keep sum and count of each grade together:

```
struct grade_info {
 unsigned count = 0;
 double sum = 0;
};
// ... later in the main function
 std::array<grade_info, 5> grades;
 // input
 for (auto const & grade : grades) { // C++11 shorthand to iterate over a collection
  // use grade.count and grade.sum
 }
```

Concerning your input:

```
for (scores; cin >> scores;){
```

This does the right thing, but is a bit strange. Since `scores` will only be used inside that loop instead of declaring it as local variable of `main` we only declare it inside the loop:

```
for (double score; // only a single score is in that variable at any time
     cin >> score; // ends the loop on eof or failure to convert to double (when text got entered)
     // no step instructions, the above check does that already
     ) {
```

Now there's also no need to test `cin` inside the loop. The `operator>>` returns (a reference to) its first argument, which is `cin`, so the test in the for loop already tests `cin`, no need for `if (! cin) { break; }`.

Then you have code like this

```
grade = 'A';
```

when you never use the value stored in `grade`. Just remove that.

Last but not least your input validation isn't working (the 101 in my test case is treated as grade B):

```
if (scores > 85 && scores <= 100) {
 // scores between (85, 100]
}
// scores is either <= 85 OR > 100
else if (scores > 75){
 // scores is in (75, 85] OR > 100
}
```

Ideally you should keep input validation and business logic separated:

```
if (not input_is_valid(score)) {
 continue; // the loop
}
// business logic, assuming valid input
```

So, the final code could be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct grade_info {
 unsigned count = 0;
 double sum = 0;
 char const name;
 grade_info(char n) : name(n) {
 }
};
bool input_is_valid(double score) {
 return (score >= 0) and (score <= 100);
}
std::size_t score_to_grade_index(double score) {
 if (score >= 85) {
  return 0;
 } else if (score >= 75) {
  return 1;
 } else if (score >= 65) {
  return 2;
 } else if (score >= 55) {
  return 3;
 } else {
  return 4;
 }
}

int main(int, char**) {
 std::array<grade_info, 5> grades {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'};
 for (double score; std::cin >> score;) {
  if (not input_is_valid(score)) {
   continue;
  }
  auto index = score_to_grade_index(score);
  ++(grades[index].count);
  grades[index].sum += score;
 }
 for (auto const & grade : grades) {
  std::cout << "# " << grade.name << ": "
                  << grade.count;
  if (grade.count > 0) {
   std::cout << " avg: " << (grade.sum / grade.count);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

[Live here](http://ideone.com/f20nPY)